# IIS {SERVER_NAME} not returning hostname

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, dns

Using IIS "Server 2016" v10.0.14393.0, I have a web.config URLRewrite rule to redirect inbound connections to the NodeJS app that handles them:

```xml
<rule name="WebSocket" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="wsapp/(.*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}:7899/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

The server is accessed using a DNS/F5 alias that embeds the IIS server's listening port number: `https://test-server/wsapp/local/47143` which resolves to one of the two load-balanced servers.

Two years ago, this rewrite would direct the client to the FQDN of the server that the F5 chose: `307 - Location: https://mqa907b422x.testing.com:7899/local/47143` **but now IT IS NOT!**

Now, it is reusing the DNS alias and sending the client to the entirely bogus address `https://test-server:7899/local/47143` which has 2 port numbers and an inaccessible path.

I looked in `/Windows/system/drivers/etc/hosts` and it says "localhost is resolved using DNS" with no lines regarding the local hostname.

How does IIS resolve `{SERVER_NAME}`?  When I do an `nslookup` on the box, it returns the hosts actual name, but IIS does not! How did someone futz it up?  What should I change to restore the correct functionality of *"The server's host name, DNS alias, or IP address as it would appear in self-referencing URLs."*? (The alias being returned is not self-referencing, it's a load-balancer alias.)

BTW, GitHub Copilot (ChatGPT) says that this new behavior is correct and that `{SERVER_NAME}` is taken from the `Host:` header of the request, but this is not what the documentation says, nor is it my previous experience. `{SERVER_NAME}`was used specifically to bypass DNS aliases and get a connection to the local machine.

Comment: Have you tried changing `{SERVER_NAME}` to `{HTTP_HOST}` in the rewrite rule? `HTTP_HOST`: Returns the name of the Web server. This may or may not be the same as SERVER_NAME depending on type of name resolution you are using on your Web server (IP address, host header).
`SERVER_NAME`: The server's host name, DNS alias, or IP address as it would appear in self-referencing URLs.

Comment: {HTTP_HOST} returns the inbound Host header which is the behavior I’m trying to avoid.

Comment: Please try using FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @YurongDai that was a good exercise, but unfortunately, all it shows me is the before/after which adds no new information, even though 'verbose' is on. There's no indication why `{SERVER_NAME}` is not using the DNS name of the host but the F5 alias. It does mark the rewrite as 'cache unsafe' so it *thinks* it's actually altering the request's hostname, but it's not.